# How can I turn an GPIO to its alternate function?

Tags: hardware, gpio, electronics

I want to use the altenate function of GPIO 4 namely the GPCLK0 function. 
How can one set a GPIO to its alternate function? Many alternate functions are summarized here: [elinux-wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals)

The best would be if it is possible with the [wiringPi Library](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/). But i do not mind to use arbitrary C-code if someone tells me how to do it.
After entering an alternative function, i think it is needed to configure it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following C Macro to change a given GPIO to an alternate function as specified by this table: http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs

```
volatile unsigned *gpio;

#define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)<<(((g)%10)*3))
```

Example (from http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_hardware_hacking)

The following C Macros would change GPIO g to its ALT0 function:

```
INP_GPIO(g);
SET_GPIO_ALT(g,0);
```

Always use INP_GPIO(x) before using SET_GPIO_ALT(x,y)

```
#define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
```

Comment: Wow.  That first macro is...unbelievable.  Would you mind explaining how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Using the pigpio library to setup GPIO 4 as ALT0 function i.e. GPCLK0:

```
$ pigs m 4 0
```

Ref.: [changing mode of GPIO](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#M/MODES)

Answer (score 0):

here are some other threads (on [www.raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org)) that are dealing with the `GPCLK0` function.

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11127
- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=17975

the second link has an exact C example on how to set the GPCLK0 alternate function.

```
/* Setup GPIO 4 as ALT0 function i.e. GPCLK0 */
mov r0, #4
mov r1, #4 /* ALT0 */
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, i tried a littlebit with that assembler-code, but i think assembler is not my thing. This takes longer than exspected..

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows different ways you can configure the GPIO pins, such as bash, python, and C using wiringPi. It's as easy as an Arduino.

http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-like-an-arduino

You'll need to look into the WiringPi library a little more to know exactly what to set for the specific "alternate function" you want, eg SPI, PWM, I²C etc, since you didn't specify.

Comment: Link requires account to read, if it's even still alive.

Comment: Looks like it might have been taken over, or being migrated. I found it in the wayback cache at https://web.archive.org/web/20121214004835/http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-like-an-arduino 

Short version in case that disappears too (this may be way out of date, since it was 2013):

Python: sudo pip install rpi.gpio
```import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, True)
GPIO.output(7,False)```

C: get WiringPi library from http://wiringpi.com/ - it is not on github.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set the alt function

```
static void bcm2708_set_gpio_alt(int pin, int alt)
{
    /*
     * This is the common way to handle the GPIO pins for
     * the Raspberry Pi.
     * TODO This is a hack. Use pinmux / pinctrl.
     */
#define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)        <<(((g)%10)*3))
    unsigned int *gpio;
    gpio = ioremap(GPIO_BASE, SZ_16K);
    INP_GPIO(pin);
    SET_GPIO_ALT(pin, alt);
    iounmap(gpio);
#undef INP_GPIO
#undef SET_GPIO_ALT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [pigpio](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library can do this for several languages, including python (which is where I needed it).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pigpio

RTS=17
pi = pigpio.pi()
if pi.connected:
    # Configure RTS0 for alt function 3
    pi.set_mode(RTS, pigpio.ALT3)
```